# Backbone return to the same route on page refresh

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes, refresh

I have the following code:

```
// /views/view.js
App.NavBarView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: _.template('<a href="page1"></a>'),
    render: function () {// some code here},
    events: {
        'click a': 'reroute'
    },
    reroute: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        App.Router.navigate($(e.target).attr('href'), {trigger: true});
    }
});

// js/app.js
var appRouter = new App.Router({
    main: $('#main'),
});
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
```

When I clicked on the anchor, I will get the following results:

```
//localhost:3000/page1
```

Which is okay. But when I execute a page refresh (cmd + R for Mac)(F5 for windows), I got the following error:

```
// Cannot GET /page1
```

How can I reroute the page back to the same url (localhost/page1) when I clicked on the refresh button?

Comment: if you are refreshing the page, it means all of your javascript objects are reinitialized (including backbone.history).

Comment: I see, so there are no way around it?

Comment: Do you have routes defined for `/page1`?

Comment: No I do not. This is only done on a static website without any server backend.